# Window created with Qt Designer very small when run in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I created a window in Qt Designer. When shown from within Designer, it looks like this:
[image: 1]

But when I run my code in Python, the same window is very small, like this:
[image: 2]

How do I make it display the same size as in Designer?

Comment: Change the width,length in the code, along with the resolution.

Comment: change where bro ??? i dont understand. I was set minximum screen, but not work

Comment: increase button width,lenth,font size etc..

Comment: Hmm... Do you have a 4K monitor, and is your OS set to scale its UI?